# Add submenus to Theme options menu

Tags: theme-development, add-menu-page

My theme currently has a single menu on the left hand sidebar of WP admin. I want to include submenus on that menu.

How can I add, for example, a single submenu item to the "Theme Options" menu below?

```
add_menu_page(
    "My Theme Options", 
    "Theme Options", 
    'edit_themes', 
    basename(__FILE__), 
    'my_admin', 
    get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/img/favicon.png'
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you would use [**`add_submenu_page()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page).

But I would **strongly recommend** against making submenu pages for Theme options. To begin with, you should be using [**`add_theme_page()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page) for your Theme options page, so that your Theme options page itself is properly placed as an **Appearance** sub-menu page.

Comment: wrap the function `add_theme_page()` inside a function and hook the wrapper function to `admin_menu` action hook.
`add_action('admin_menu', 'add_theme_page_wrapper_function');`

Answer (score 1):

Use [add_submenu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)

It uses pretty much the same structure, but takes the parent-menu slug or file name as the first argument.